# How do I transfer the underscore to the left side?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
    *****-
    ***-
    *-
```

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int height=0; height<5; height+=2){
            for(int width=5; width-height>0; width--){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("-");        
        }
    }
```

Also, I'm trying to make it look like this so it would look like an upside down pyramid for our assignment using only for loops.

```
-*****
--***
---*
```

Comment: Change `System.out.println("-");` to `System.out.println();` and put `System.out.print("-");` before the start of the inner loop

Comment: Then put a loop around it to print as many as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the underscores appear on the left of the pyramid, just change when you output the dash. Make sure to still create a new line after each loop still though.

Example of dash on left:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for(int height=0; height<5; height+=2)
    {
        System.out.print("-");
        for(int width=5; width-height>0; width--)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is a method that will flip the pyramid. I changed up some of your for loops for this one but it is pretty straight forward. Just change the value of the pyramidHeight variable to change the height of the pyramid output.

Example of flipped pyramid:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int pyramidHeight = 3;
    for(int height=0; height<pyramidHeight; height++)
    {
        for(int width=height+1; width>0; width--)
        {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        for(int width = 1 + (((pyramidHeight-1) - height) * 2); width>0; width--)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for the first part do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int height=0;height<5;height+=2) {
        System.out.print("-");
        for(int width=5;width-height>0;width--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

AND for the second part do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int height=2;height>=0;height--) {
        for(int _under=0;(_under+height)!=3;_under++) {
            System.out.print("-");   
        }
        for(int width=0;width<(2*height+1);width++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int height=0; height<5; height+=2){
        for(int curHeight= height+1; curHeight > 0; curHeight-=2){
            System.out.print("-"); 
        }

        for(int width=5; width-height>0; width--){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```